# MDADM reshape 2 disk raid 5 to 4 disk raid6

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have a somewhat non-standard mdadm reshape going on. I have a 2 disk raid5 (clean state) which I want to reshape into a 4 disk raid6. The reason this was created as a 2 disk raid5 instead of a 2 disk raid1 was that I read somewhere this would be easier to reshape in the future. This does not seem to be the case:

```
~# mdadm --grow /dev/md3 --level 6 --raid-devices 4 --backup /root/md3reshapebackup
mdadm: /dev/md3: could not set level to raid6
```

I then tried to use a 3 disk raid6 as an intermediate step, but this did not work as well:

```
root@bigbrain:~# mdadm --grow /dev/md3 --raid-devices=3 --level=6 --layout=preserve --backup /root/md3reshapebackup
mdadm: /dev/md3: could not set level to raid6
```

The option `layout=preserve` was meant to save me and the disks from having to do restriping twice.

Now I am first growing to a 3 disk raid5 and hope from there I can go to a 4 disk raid6:

```
root@bigbrain:~# mdadm --grow /dev/md3 --raid-devices=3 --backup /root/md3reshapebackup
mdadm: Need to backup 1024K of critical section..
```

Will this work and would there have been any other way? Would the conversion from 2 disk raid1 to 4 disk raid6 have been possible in one go?

Comment: 2 disks in RAID5 with clean state ??? RAID5 should have at least 3 disks. RAID5 on its own is real PITA when disk failed.

Comment: For mdadm, a 2 disk raid5 is equivalent to a 2 disk raid1. You can convert one into the other instantly just by `mdadm --grow /dev/md? --level 1/5`.

Comment: Try to disconnect one out of 2 of your disk in RAID5 and attempt to boot.

Comment: The array is not my boot device, so boot compatibility is not an issue. By now the array is undergoing the second reshape towards a 4 disk raid6 after the reshape to a 3 disk raid5 finished.

Comment: That's up to you, I told you that using RAID5/6 is a way to looking for a trouble. RAID5/6 is basically stripe (as a RAID0 where data redistributed across whole array) with added parity, when one disk would fail it is nightmare performance and recovery. When you adding new disk, recovery  takes way too long time. Usually one building RAIDs with the same type/brand HDD, so possibility that other disks might fail during recovery is very high and if it happened, you will loose the whole array. HDD are cheap, if you care about integrity and performance go with RAID10 and better with ZFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revisiting this after a while, because the next upgrade to my server is in order. Per http://neil.brown.name/blog/20090817000931 the path for upgrading from 2 disks (raid1 or raid5 which is basically the same) to a 4 disk raid6 is only supported via a 3 disk raid 5, so two full reshape steps really seem to be necessary.